# Police(?) taking relics from a church. What is the background?

Tags: religion

In [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=RnaCkFQ5B2Q) one can see police (or some other people in black uniform) taking relics by force from a church. What is the background of the event?

Comment: You're going to have to find a russian speaker to translate it.  Then you need to determine if it's real or just filmed for a movie.  *Then* we might be able to answer questions about it.

Comment: Re:  "people in black uniform": The subtitle of Youtube video calls them "Приставы". They are basically an executive law enforcement agency that enforces court orders [home page](http://fssprus.ru/), [Wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2). The closest English equivalent I can think of is bailiffs

Comment: The specific incident was covered by this article in detail: https://news.pn/ru/incidents/130277

Answer (score 4):

The answer is simple: the parish where the event happens belongs to Russian Orthodox Authonomous Church, also known as "Suzdal schism". The Russian government currently supports only the Orthodox Church of Moscow Patriarchate and charcks down with any "non-traditional confessions", sects and schisms and heresies.

In recent years tens of parishes of ROACh has been closed down or transferred to Moscow Patriarchate under various pretexts (such as poor maintenance of the buildings for instance).